# Augmentation layers only for specific classes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

For the classification task, I would like to apply [Augmentation Layers](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_augmentation/) (augmentation), **only for specific classes**.

The rationale: In case of an unbalanced dataset I would like to improve model performance for classes with a small number of images.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RandomFlip

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use `tf.data.Dataset()` and a `.map()` function where you could verify the label in it, therefore performing augmentation only on that specific label.

```
def process_function(filepath):
    label = retrieve_class_label(filepath=filepath)
    image = tf.io.read_file(filename=filepath)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT])

    # Presume the label is of the form "root_folder/class_name"
    label = tf.strings.split(filepath, '\\')[-1]
    return image, label


def augment_function(image, label):
    if tf.math.equal(class_underrepresented, label):
         image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    return image, label
```

Comment: Thx @Timubus! Do you familiar with an option of doing the above using augmentation layers: https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_augmentation/  or ImageDataGenerator: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator ?

Comment: Yes I am familiar, and this is why I suggested that you use tf.data.Dataset(). The first one is indeed a layer in your model, and you cannot control the flow once you put it in the model, all the data will pass through it. The second one again, does not give you low-level control. The two solutions would be tf.data.Dataset() or to subclass Sequence() class,to have control on the batches you generate.

Comment: @MichaelD did you understand/may I help you more with regard to your question?